# Why won't a query sort by a calculated column in a database table avter a VS 2017 to VS 2019 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-core

After migrating from Visual Studio 2017 to 2019 an application I'm working on, no longer sorts on a calculated field (FullName).

The calculated field concatenates the LastName and FirstName fields to form the Fullname field.  The FullName field is use for sorting and populating a SelectList.  Everything worked as expected in VS 2017 CORE 2.2.  An error message appears indicating the the FullName field cannot be found.

I do not see a FullName column in the database, (DB table name is Speaker). If I comment out the orderby (orderby s.FullName) portion of the query the SelectList is populated, the the names are not in alphabetical order

Listed in the code section in the code to create the table (Model) an the query in the OnPost method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PublicTalkSchedule.Models
{
    public class Speaker
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Speaker #:")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
        public string spkLastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
        public string spkFirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email:")]
        public string spkEmail { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E/MS:")]
        public string EldMs {get;set;}

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "")]
        public string FullName { get { return string.Concat(spkLastName + ", "
            + spkFirstName); } }

        [Display(Name = "Companyy:")]
        public string CompName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CompId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompId")]
        public virtual Congregation Congregation { get; set; }

    }


// query speaker table to get a list of all speakers, insert them into 
//the SelectList (SpkID)
IQueryable<string> spknameQuery = from s in _db.Speaker       
                                  orderby s.FullName
                                  select s.FullName;

SpkId = new SelectList(await spknameQuery.ToListAsync());
```

What do I have to do to the query to sort the the calculated field.  Should there be an actual column in the database named FullName?

Comment: You have indicated that `FullName` is `[NotMapped]` so my guess is the query will not know how to order by a column that does not exist. Can you order by last name, first name?

Comment: Could you share more details that could reproduce your issue?It could work well in my project in vs 2019.

Comment: Rena - I followed your first suggestion of using the spkLastName and spkFirstName  for the orderby criteria, that worked:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code in the following sample and the names are in alphabetical order:

1.Model:

```
public class Speaker
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "Speaker #:")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
    public string spkLastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string spkFirstName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat(spkLastName + ", "
+ spkFirstName);
            }
        }
    [Display(Name = "Companyy:")]
    public string CompName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompId")]
    public virtual Congregation Congregation { get; set; }
}
public class Congregation
{
    [Key]
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public string CompName { get; set; }
}
```

2.Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<h1>Index</h1>
<form method="post">
    <input name="companyName" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
@{
    if (Model.SpkId != null)
    {
        <select name="authorId" asp-items="Model.SpkId"></select>
    }
}
```

3.Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly YourContext _db;

    public IndexModel(YourContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public SelectList SpkId { get; set; }

    public void OnGetAsync()
    {
    }
    public async Task OnPostAsync(string companyName)
    {
        IQueryable<string> spknameQuery = from s in _db.Speaker
                                          orderby s.FullName
                                          select s.FullName;

        SpkId = new SelectList(await spknameQuery.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

4.Result:
[image]